# Redirecting URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect URL, using .htaccess. I have the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

This is working correctly if I don't use dot in the URL. But if I want to access for example this URL:

```
load/com.example.unique.id
```

then I will get error 404. Of course, I can understand why is this: I haven't include the dot in my expression. However if I include it, I will get error 500.

I tried to include dot in the expression like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the '-' in [a-zA-Z0-9_-.], try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot but hyphen needs to be last or at first position in character class to avoid escaping. Correct regex based rule will be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/([\w.-]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```